# Can the Amazon Firefly SDK be used on the kindle fire?

Tags: android, amazon-firefly

I want to use the amazon firefly sdk on kindle fires.
The SDK documentation only talks about using it on the Fire Phone.
**Is there any documentation that definitively says that the firefly sdk is a fire phone exclusive?**

Answer (score 1):

I sent an email to Amazon and this is the response I have gotten:

> Thank you for writing in.
>   The Firefly SDK is exclusively available for the Fire phone and would not be available for Kindle Fire.

So official word from amazon is that firefly is a fire phone exclusive